# How to prevent Safari from loading back button cache?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, safari

I've noticed a common bug with browser back button usage on my web app where hitting the back button after logout loads a cached page where the user appears logged in (though they aren't actually).

I found a lot of [helpful questions with helpful answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788802/prevent-safari-loading-from-cache-when-back-button-is-clicked) and employed the fixes folks suggested, including every combination of suggested Cache-Control options in the header:

```
('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0, max-stale=0')
```

And the header works on *most* browsers, even with just no-cache and no-store, but no header options solve this on Safari.

Sure enough, the most reliable way I can find to resolve this for Safari is to use some javascript as such which forces a reload:

```
<script>
            window.onpageshow = function(event) {
                if (event.persisted) {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            };
</script>
```

The javascript block above *does* work, but only if the user doesn't disable javascript via Safari -> Preferences -> Security and subsequently hit the back button. It's very much an edge case, but I'm kind of fascinated that such a popular browser makes such a trivial bug this tricky!

If anybody has found a way to make Safari play nice without javascript I'd love to hear how. Thanks all in advance!