# Div above responsive image map

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add an arrow over a image that has an image map. It uses [mapify](https://github.com/etienne-martin/Mapify) to make the image map responsive.

I already tried implementing the code in every place I could think of on this page: https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/lobby.html. The idea is to replace the arrows that you see in the picture with arrows

I tested and the arrow works over an image. Here's the fiddle where you can check how it should work.

https://jsfiddle.net/spored3v/7557heze/4/

The code of the page contains a lot of JS to handle different resolutions so most of the HTML code is contained in a switch case. Another part of the code is there to create some highlight effect for mapped elements (no element is highlighted yet).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Bare - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Normalize CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css" integrity="sha256-HxaKz5E/eBbvhGMNwhWRPrAR9i/lG1JeT4mD6hCQ7s4=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <!-- Mapify CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\jquery.mapify.css">    

    <!-- Project's Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">    

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Page Content -->
        <!--<img src="images/schita-usi-1.jpg" id="fullheight" style="height:100vh; width: 100%">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="index-page-3">
            </div>
        </a>-->     
        <div id="black-cover"></div>
            <a href="https://sporedev.ro" target="_blank"><div href="#" class="arrow arrow-right active animate-right-to-left"><span class="room-desc">Decanat</span></div></a> 
        <div id="resp-background-img-full-height">
        </div>
        <audio autoplay>
          <source src="lobby.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery Version 1.10.2 -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Detect the browser's aspect ratio and serve different HTML -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function gcd(a, b) {
          if (b > a) {
            temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp
          }
          while (b != 0) {
            m = a % b;
            a = b;
            b = m;
          }
          return a;
        }

        /* ratio is to get the gcd and divide each component by the gcd, then return a string with the typical colon-separated value */
        function ratio(x, y) {
          c = gcd(x, y);
          return "" + (x / c) + ":" + (y / c)
        }

        var ratio = ratio(screen.width, screen.height)
        var imgContainer = document.querySelector('#resp-background-img-full-height')

        switch (ratio) {
          // case "16:9":
            // imgContainer.innerHTML = '<img src="images/test-rata-de-aspect.jpg">'        
            // break        
          // case "4:3":
            // imgContainer.innerHTML = '<img src="images/schita-usi-2.jpg">'
            // break
          default:
            var htmlcode = '<img src="images/Lobby.jpg" usemap="#map" class="map full-img" width="1920px" height="1080px">';
            htmlcode += '<map name="map" id="map"">';
            htmlcode += '<area shape="poly" coords="1301,992,1346,996,1354,945,1308,941" href="#" alt="contact">';
            htmlcode += '<area shape="poly" coords="1356,995,1404,999,1416,948,1368,946" href="#" alt="setari">';
            htmlcode += '<area shape="poly" coords="1420,1001,1471,1006,1477,953,1424,951" href="#" alt="login">';
            htmlcode += '<area shape="poly" coords="1354,935,1365,883,1320,881,1310,933" href="index.html" alt="home">';
            htmlcode += '<area shape="poly" coords="1370,933,1417,937,1428,885,1381,883" href="lobby.html" alt="lobby">';
            htmlcode += '<area shape="poly" coords="1440,883,1493,885,1488,941,1432,939" href="hol.html" alt="programe">';
            htmlcode += '<area shape="poly" coords="1324,866,1373,866,1382,818,1335,818" href="#" alt="back" onclick="window.history.back();">';
            htmlcode += '<area shape="poly" coords="1382,868,1433,869,1444,816,1392,817" href="#" alt="descriere">';
            htmlcode += '<area shape="poly" coords="1446,868,1492,871,1501,818,1452,817" href="#" alt="harta">';    
            htmlcode += '</map>';
            htmlcode += '<a href="https://sporedev.ro" target="_blank"><div href="#" class="arrow arrow-right active animate-right-to-left"><span class="room-desc">Decanat</span></div></a>';
            imgContainer.innerHTML = htmlcode;
            break    
        }   
    </script>
    <!-- Load Mapify -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mapify.js"></script>
    <!-- Mapify script -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("img[usemap]").mapify();
    </script>
    <!-- Load Zoom -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/zoom.js"></script>   
    <script>
        // Safari hack for reloading page when back button is pressed
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788802/prevent-safari-loading-from-cache-when-back-button-is-clicked
        $(window).bind("pageshow", function(event) {
                if (event.originalEvent.persisted) {
                        window.location.reload() 
                }
        });

        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#black-cover").fadeOut(2000, "swing");
        })

        function zoomTo(polygonId) {
            zoom.to({
                element: $(".mapify-polygon")[polygonId],

                padding: 100,

                callback: function() {
                    $("#resp-background-img-full-height").fadeOut(1500, "linear", function() {
                        window.location.href = 'hol.html';
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script>
var timeout;
function blinkIn() {
   timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $("#map area").filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2), :eq(3), :eq(4), :eq(5), :eq(6), :eq(7), :eq(8), :eq(9), :eq(10), :eq(11), :eq(12), :eq(13), :eq(14)').trigger("mouseenter.mapify").trigger("focus.mapify").trigger("touchend.mapify");
    $(".mapify-svg polygon").filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2), :eq(3), :eq(4), :eq(5), :eq(6), :eq(7), :eq(8), :eq(9), :eq(10), :eq(11), :eq(12), :eq(13), :eq(14)').css("stroke", "#FFF").css('opacity', '0.3').css('stroke-dasharray', '50').css('stroke-dashoffset', '100').css('animation', 'dash 1.5s linear forwards');
    blinkOut();
  }, 3000);
}

function blinkOut() {
   setTimeout(function() {
    $("#map area").filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2), :eq(3), :eq(4), :eq(5), :eq(6), :eq(7), :eq(8), :eq(9), :eq(10), :eq(11), :eq(12), :eq(13), :eq(14)').trigger('mouseout.mapify');
    $(".mapify-svg polygon").filter(':eq(0), :eq(1), :eq(2), :eq(3), :eq(4), :eq(5), :eq(6), :eq(7), :eq(8), :eq(9), :eq(10), :eq(11), :eq(12), :eq(13), :eq(14)').css("stroke", "").css('opacity', '').css('stroke-dasharray', '').css('stroke-dashoffset', '').css('animation', '');;
    blinkIn();
  }, 1500);
}

blinkIn();
$(document).click(function(e) { clearTimeout(timeout); blinkIn(); });
    </script>       
</body>

</html>
```

I did some research on both SO and other website, trying out a bunch of guides about positioning but I think that the problem is not in the way I tried to position the element but in the JS that is running on the page.

Creating a test page and that fiddle further proved my theory.

My question is: how can I make an element appear on top of a responsive image map?

Answer (score 0):

It was not a JS related problem, I just didn't noticed that the image uses a z-index.

I applied a z-index to the div and everything worked.

For more information about z-index you can check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Sorry for wasting people's time with a basic mistake.