# JS: reload() whole website after forward-back navigation mobile IOS only

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, browser, reload

My project is a one-pager using simple css and js, gsap for timelines and animation.

I tested reloading my website with a button 'onclick' with window.location.reload().
Works fine!

If user swipes in browsers history, I tried:

```html
window.addEventListener('pageshow', function (e) {
    if(e.persisted) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
```

On desktop it works. On Android it works. But on IOS mobile pure chaos. It seems that scripts are loaded several times, the performance is slow, all browsers,...

How can I reload the whole website on mobile after using browser history navigation?

br chris

Answer (score 0):

Because `pageshow` run after `load`, so, you can:

```js
window.addEventListener('pagehide', function(e) {
    var $body = $(document.body);
    $body.children().remove();
    // after callback, run this script
    setTimeout(function() {
        $body.append("<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.reload();<\/script>");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't solve the issue on IOS. Wait 10 min before swiping back in history and the reload works. Maybe it seems to be a special cache issue.

Comment: I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27070705/11226734