# Trying to execute a javascript function when users click on back/forward button after redirect

Tags: javascript, navigation, browser-history

I want to execute a js function when users click on back/forward button **after redirect**. I have a half working function below:

```
detectHistoryEvent();
function detectHistoryEvent() {
  console.log(performance.navigation.type); // deprecated
  console.log(performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type); // currently used
  if (performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type && performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type === 'back_forward') {
    themethod(); // method I want to run
  }
}
```

Working Scenario 1:

1. On `PAGE 1` user clicks delete button that executes `POST REQUEST`.
2. If successful, it will redirect to `PAGE 2`.
3. From `PAGE 2` when user clicks on back button, it will redirect to `PAGE 1`.  After redirection, it will execute `themethod()` because of the function above. This is because the value of navigation is `back_forward`.

Not Working Scenario 2:

1. On `PAGE 1` user clicks href that executes `GET REQUEST`.
2. If successful, it will redirect to `PAGE 2`.
3. From `PAGE 2` when user clicks on back button, it will redirect to `PAGE 1`. However the `themethod()` is not executed. This is because the value of nagivation is `navigate` just like a normal href click.

Is it possible to check if user clicks on back/forward button even if `PAGE 1` executes `GET REQUEST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of searching, removed the method on my question and use the solution using the code below instead:

```
window.onpageshow = function(event) {
  if (event.persisted) {
      themethod();
  }
};
```

[Original answer on another SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13123626)