# How to destroy session variable when logout process is occured

Tags: php

I used all the process for destroying session.

```
 header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
 header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 session_destroy();
 session_unset();
 clearstatcache();
```

But when i click the back button it show my previous page with session value. 
I don't know how to solve it. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start the session before:

```
session_start();
```

see [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a misunderstanding.

When pressing the <kbd>back</kbd> button, you are most likely seeing a cached version of the page in the browser. This does **not** mean that you are still logged in.

Try refreshing the previous page. It should show the login dialog.

If you want to prevent the page from being shown in this way, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297122/preventing-cache-on-back-button-in-safari-5/5305905#5305905) is an approach for turning off the browser's caching.

If you actually remain logged in, then something is wrong. In that case, we need to see some code.

Comment: you're welcome. if my answer solved your problem accept my answer.