# Session.Clear() doesn't work with Safari

Tags: asp.net, session, safari

I'm doing a project with asp.net webforms. And I've discovered something I can not understand. On a certain page I need to delete all session variables. To do this I use Session.Clear () in the Page_Load method. In all browsers except Safari the behavior is correct. Session.Clear () does its job and session variables are deleted. But in Safari on Mac OS X and iOS (Safari or Chrome, since iOS all use UIWebView) session variables are not deleted with the problem that this generates when using the go back or forward buttons. How is this possible if session variables are controlled from the server? Someone with the same problem? Any solution? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [session.abandon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310(v=vs.90).aspx) ?

Comment: Yes. But I don't want to destroy de session. I just want to delete all the variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was Safari caching. I was able to solve the problem with this thread [Preventing cache on back-button in Safari 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297122/preventing-cache-on-back-button-in-safari-5)